# Repeating an HTML element with incrementing variables

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I currently have a simple html list. What I want is to repeat this list item with each repeated element having a variable that will increase by one, each time it is repeated.

The php calls that i have included in the above list item is from the Advanced Custom Field plugin on WordPress. The variable I want to change is the number inside of those php calls.

```
<ul>
 <li>

  <?php the_field('vendor_1_name'); ?> <!--the number is the variable that i want to increase by one with each repition-->
  <a href="http://<?php the_field('vendor_1_url'); ?>" target="_blank"/>
    <?php the_field('vendor_1_url'); ?>
  </a>

 </li>

</ul>
```

I have an idea of how to do this using an array, but I would love to hear other methods on how to do something like this. Thanks!

Comment: How many times should it iterate?

Comment: Your <a> tag has a typo. It should not be self-closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <?php for ($z = 0; $z < $n; $z++) : ?>
  <li>
     <?php the_field('vendor_'.$z.'_name'); ?>
     <a href="http://<?php the_field('vendor_'.$z.'_url'); ?>" target="_blank">
        <?php the_field('vendor_'.$z.'_url'); ?>
     </a>
   </li>
   <?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

Where `$n` is the number of times it should iterate.

Comment: && you'll want PHP to echo the <li> & <a> tags.

Comment: This does just what I want it to do. Would there be any way to declare the first for variable as a global variable? I have a few lists like that that I would like to use this for and it seems pointless to declare different variables for each list that are essentially doing the same thing. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop. If you have an array of items (are you grabbing vendors from a database?), just iterate through the array:

```
<?php

// fetch values and define $vendors
// using sql is highly recommended

echo "<ul>\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($vendors); $i++) {
    echo "<li><a href='".$vendors[$i]['vendor_url']."'>".$vendors[$i]['vendor_name']."</a></li>\n";
}

echo "</ul>\n";

?>
```

Note that the array would say `vendor_name` instead of `vendor_1_name` because the field is not going to have the iteration in its name.